# Camel - trying to hit endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, endpoint

I am new to camel. I am trying to learn by writing a simple app.
I have a small project setup and i am trying to hit an endpoint i found online. The enpoint does return json.

The error i am getting is:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> 
To[https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[direct:httpRoute]] -> [SetHeader[CamelHt... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums due to: No component found with scheme: https
```

and

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums due to: No component found with scheme: https
```

here is the main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try {

        camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        camelContext.stop();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**MyRouteBuilder**

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:httpRoute").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
            .to("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
            .process(new AlbumProcessor());
    }
}
```

**AlbumProcessor**

```
public class AlbumProcessor implements Processor {


@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));

}
```

}

camel-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<bean id="routeBuilder" class="com.learncamel.MyRouteBuilder" />
<bean id="processor" class="com.learncamel.AlbumProcessor" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder" />
</camelContext>
```

pom should have all the dependencies. like:

pom

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is much appreciated as i am just trying to learn at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `camel-http` dependency is in `test` scope, try to remove `<scope>test</scope>` in pom.xml

Comment: now i get : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpCommonComponent: method <init>()V not found

Comment: Then remove `httpcore` from pom to avoid version mismatch. `camel-http` already contains required dependencies.

Comment: I did this and i dont get an error but the processor is never called from("direct:httpRoute").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET")) .toD("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?bridgeEndpoint=true") .process(new AlbumProcessor())

Comment: Now this is correct. It will not be called with your current route. You need add some trigger. The simpliest trigger is timer: `from("timer:hello").to("direct:httpRoute")`. (Add camel-timer dependency to your pom and make sure to use the same version for all dependencies from `org.apache.camel` group)

Comment: thanks so much. Its calling the processor now.

Comment: if you put this into an Answer i can approve it

Answer (score 0):

Add `?bridgeEndpoint=true` to your uri.

*Edited after **Bedla** pointed out the error in my answer.

Comment: `.to("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?bridgeEndpoint=true")`

Comment: This answer is not correct for Camel 3.3. `http4` and `https4` was removed in Camel 3.x. You should be able to use `http` and `https` endpoints just fine.

Comment: @Bedla yes, i was just going through the docs and I noticed this.

Comment: I did this and i dont get an error but the processor is never called
       from("direct:httpRoute").setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
                .toD("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                .process(new AlbumProcessor());